# What causes a C program not to increment variable correctly in Arduino?

Tags: python, c, arduino, raspberry-pi, microcontroller

I am trying to establish a connection between Raspberry PI and an Ardunio, where Python is running on the PI. the goal is to verify that Arduino is connected and sending correct values, the connection seems to be established as I am receiving on the Python terminal, but the `a` value is not coming correctly, it is incrementing by 2, sometime more than two.
Can this be a connection delay issue? a serial (USB) issue?

**serial_text.ino** (running on Arduino) :

```
char dataString[50] = {0};
int a =0; 

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);              //Starting serial communication
}

void loop() {
 // a++;                          // a value increase every loop
  //sprintf(dataString,"%02X",a); // convert a value to hexa 
  Serial.println(++a);   // send the data
  delay(1000);                  // give the loop some break
}
```

**Serial_test.py** (Running on the PI) :

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
s = [0,1]
while True:
    read_serial=ser.readline()
    s[0] = str(int (ser.readline(),16))
    print "a value from controller = ", s[0]
    //print read_serial
```

**OUTPUT** (on PI screen) :

[image]

**UPDATE:** 
i made some changes, but it's still the same problem , here are the changes:

**serial_text.ino** (running on Arduino) :

```
int a =0; 

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);              //Starting serial communication
}

void loop() {

  a++;
  Serial.println(a);   // send the data
  delay(1000);                  // give the loop some break
}
```

For Python, I only changed this line:

```
s[0] = str(int (ser.readline(),16))
```

TO:

```
s[0] = str(int (ser.readline(),10))
```

I also removed  `//print read_serial` just in case.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: This is not your real code. The screenshot doesn't match the `print` in your program.

Comment: you sent it as decimal value but after receiving you convert as hex value `int(..., 16)` ? Are you sure you don't run code with `a++;` ?

Comment: I know, i wrote the print statement here, but it's the same, the last print statement is commented (in C comment), too i know, but that's the code running basically

Comment: It was a++ originally, I changed it later to ++a, the same result no change

Comment: when you send decimal `10` then you receive it as `10` but `int(10, 16)` gives `16` so it skips some numbers.

Comment: you're saying it should be s[0] = str(int (ser.readline(),10)) ? , i'll try

Comment: I was asking if you use `a++;` and `Serial.println(++a);` at the same time - because it could give incrementing by 2.

Comment: I updated the codes, posted them as update.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, the problem was with line (calling readline() twice), @Adrian Jałoszewski brought it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, basically what happens here: when you do something like that:

```
Serial.println(a);
```

It sends the number as an ASCII encoded decimal, so basically if you send the integer value 12 it will send the string "12". The incrementing part works just fine here.

Why does the skipping happen? If you look closely at your code you can see, that in each iteration of the `while` loop there are two calls to `ser.readline()` this makes the skipping of every second number happen.

The reason for the larger gaps is that you receive a decimal string and treat it as an HEX string. See what happens here:

```
>>> int("49", 16)
73
>>> int("51", 16)
81
```

In decimal it's just a difference of two, but in hex it's a difference of eight - this explains the bigger gaps.

Comment: Thanks alot, the problem was with this line:  
    s[0] = str(int (ser.readline(),16)) , i changed it to  s[0] = str(int (read_serial,16))